# How to display the model value in popup window?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have returned like,

```
        return Json(model.QuestionSetList);
```

i have my view like,

```
   <input type="button" value="Sample Test" id="SampleTest" class="ButtonStyle" onclick="SampleTest.click()" tabindex="4" />
```

and i have my jquery like,

```
     // To show the model value in popup window
    $('#SampleTest').button().click(function () {
     $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,})
        var options = {};
        options.type = "POST";
        options.url = "/Dashboard/SampleTest/";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        $.ajax(options);
    });
```

By clicking the sampleTest button, it calls the SampleTest method, this methods returns a model list.I wants the model data in a popup window.But this jquery does'nt works.Its again calling the same method.
Kindly tell me how to display the model.QuestionSetList in popup window.

Comment: you have to do it in view side

Answer (score 0):

The click handled currently initializes the dialog and then performs an AJAX request. Currently you have no logic which to render the returned model inside your modal dialog, so you will have to do something of the sort:

```
// To show the model value in popup window
$('#SampleTest').button().click(function () {
      var options = {};
      options.type = "POST";
      options.url = "/Dashboard/SampleTest/";
      options.dataType = "json";
      options.contentType = "application/json";
      options.success = function (data) {
          RenderHTMLInDialog(data);
          $('#dialog').dialog({
                modal: true
          });
      };
      $.ajax(options);
});
```

This way the model is provided to your success handler of the AJAX request, you render the HTML structure that you want, append it to your dialog container with id `dialog` and initialize the dialog then.